# Creating an app with Quasar + Amplify Auth : PWA vs Android (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, quasar

I am coding a Quasar/VueJS2 solution that used **AWS Amplify Auth** (***Cognito** federated by **Google***). On the Google side, I did set an **“OAuth 2.0 Client ID”** of type **“Web application”**.

Running the project on **PWA mode** (#> quasar dev), works fine.

This is how the OAuth is done:

1. App is loaded with “Connect” button.
2. Click on “Connect” button launch auth action: Cognito then Google Authentification then return to the page who required to be connected.

But, when I build an Android version, signed the apk and installed it on my phone, I got **“Application Error” ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**.

I think that I need to set an “**OAuth 2.0 Client ID**” of type “**Android**”.

How will I manage that in Quasar? How do the code will make difference between PWA or Android mode?

This is new for me, I have never done that.